# How can I pass arguments to event handlers in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

With jQuery code like:

```
$("#myid").click(myfunction);

function myfunction(arg1, arg2) {/* something */}
```

How do I pass arguments to `myfunction` while using jQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a function with parameters as a parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300242/passing-a-function-with-parameters-as-a-parameter)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

The simplest way is to do it like so (assuming you don't want any of the event information passed to the function)...

```
$("#myid").click(function() {
    myfunction(arg1, arg2);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4Ak6/).

This create an anonymous function, which is called when the `click` event is triggered. This will in turn call `myfunction()` with the arguments you provide.

If you want to keep the [`ThisBinding`](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.1) (the value of `this` when the function is invoked, set to the element which triggered the event), then call the function with [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

```
$("#myid").click(function() {
    myfunction.call(this, arg1, arg2);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tk7yF/).

You can't pass the reference directly in the way your example states, or its single argument will be the [jQuery `event` object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

If you *do* want to pass the reference, you must leverage jQuery's [`proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) function (which is a cross browser wrapper for [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)). This lets you pass arguments, which are bound *before* the `event` argument.

```
$("#myid").click($.proxy(myfunction, null, arg1, arg2));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dLPu9/).

In this example, `myfunction()` would be executed with its `ThisBinding` intact (`null` is not an object, so the normal `this` value of the element which triggered the event is used), along with the arguments (in order) `arg1`, `arg2` and finally the jQuery `event` object, which you can ignore if it's not required (don't even name it in the function's arguments).

You could also use use the jQuery `event` object's [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/) to pass data, but this would require modifying `myfunction()` to access it via `event.data.arg1` (which aren't *function arguments* like your question mentions), or at least introducing a manual proxy function like the former example or a generated one using the latter example.

Comment: keep in mind, you'll lose the jquery context $(this) in myfunction().  To maintain, call `myfunction(this, arg1, arg2)` from the anonymous handler. Then your function can do `myfunction(el, arg1, arg2) { alert($(el).val()); }`

Comment: @geosteve: If you wanted to keep it, use `myfunction.call(this, arg1, arg2)`.

Comment: That's not passing arguments to the function, as the question asks. It's calling a function that calls another function. Nesting functions inside anonymous functions is not a good idea as you can't unbind the anonymous function easily.

Comment: @geo1701 You can if you use a custom namespace and only bind once to it. For most purposes, it's OK. But you do lose that benefit that you mentioned.

Comment: Agreed with @geo1701, I had to remove event handler and his solution is only one that worked.

Comment: @alex can you tell me how to do this in a structure with classes? : `function FancyScroll() {this.version = '1.0'; this.click = function() {console.log(this.version)}; $('#id').on('click', $.proxy(this.click, this)) } var fs = new FancyScroll();` http://jsfiddle.net/hqduwqe0/- better to read

Comment: This is the first time `$.proxy` has ever seemed clear to me.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Great answer. BTW, you can also use:
 $("#myid").click({arg1: "foo", arg2: "bar"}, myfunction). 
And the listener would look like:
function myfunction(event){
    alert(event.data.arg1);
    alert(event.data.arg2);
}

Comment: This is not at all the correct answer. It is also in no way the easiest solution and it is misleading. The solution proposed by @GeorgeFilippakos is what yo will get straight for the jQuery documentation.

Answer (score 89):

```
$("#myid").on('click', {arg1: 'hello', arg2: 'bye'}, myfunction);

function myfunction(e) {

    var arg1 = e.data.arg1;
    var arg2 = e.data.arg2;

    alert(arg1);
    alert(arg2);

}

//call method directly:
myfunction({
    arg1: 'hello agian', 
    arg2: 'bye again'
});
```

Also allows you to bind and unbind specific event handlers using the on and off methods.

Example:

```
$("#myid").off('click', myfunction);
```

This would unbind the myfunction handler from #myid

Comment: That's not passing arguments to the function, as the question asks.

Comment: That is how you pass arguments (you wrap them inside an object).

Comment: It's how you pass data, but it's a stretch calling them function arguments.

Comment: It's a better solution to the accepted answer as it uses the recommended pattern of binding and unbinding listeners using the On/Off methods.

Comment: If you think unbinding is quite rare then you must have very limited experience. Please don't poo poo contributions from others  - this is a collective knowledge base not a competition. There are no right or wrong answers.

Comment: This is what i'm using, it works on dinamically created elements, so to me it´s a much better awnser than the accepted one!

Comment: How can we use this with event delegation syntax having css selector. `$('#parent').off('click', '.child-dynamc').on('click', '.child-dynamc',{arg1: 'hello', arg2: 'bye'}, myfunction);`

Comment: Great answer. BTW, you can also use: $("#myid").click({arg1: "foo", arg2: "bar"}, myfunction). And the listener would look like: function myfunction(event){ alert(event.data.arg1); alert(event.data.arg2); }

Comment: This is my best answer for me. Just want to point out the "call method directly" code is missing the data property: `//call method directly:
myfunction({
    data: {
arg1: 'hello agian', 
    arg2: 'bye again'
}
});`

Comment: Thanks, this is will be very useful.

Answer (score 12):

while you should certainly use Alex's answer, the prototype library's "bind" method has been standardized in Ecmascript 5, and will soon be implemented in browsers natively. It works like this:

```
jQuery("#myid").click(myfunction.bind(this, arg1, arg2));
```

Comment: Will `this` be set to a different context if you use this method, for example, `bind()`ing it to `this` in that context (global) may result in that click handler having the `window` object as `this` as opposed to a reference to the `#myid` element?

Comment: @alex you are quite right. jQuery will bind the #myid element to 'this' in its event handlers, and using the bind method will override that. I wrote this post several years ago it would seem so it's hard to say what I was thinking at the time. I guess I just assume that the people reading my answers are smart enough to figure these details out themselves.

Comment: That is a very dangerous assumption.

Comment: @Travis As of this writing, (almost 11 years after Breton's answer), caniuse.com reports Ecmascript 5 is supported by **98.87%** of the browsers. (see https://caniuse.com/#search=ECMAScript%205)

Comment: @Stephan My tongue-in-cheek comment was aimed at @Breton for assuming `people reading my answers are smart enough to figure these details out themselves`, not about Ecmascript.

Answer (score 7):

There are great answers already, but anyway, here are my two cents. You can also use:

`$("#myid").click({arg1: "foo", arg2: "bar"}, myfunction)`

And the listener would look like:

`function myfunction(event){ 
    alert(event.data.arg1); 
    alert(event.data.arg2); 
}`

Comment: Internally I believe this shorthand calls `$("#myid").on('click', {arg1: "foo", arg2: "bar"}, myfunction)`

Answer (score 6):

Old thread, but for search purposes; try:

```
$(selector).on('mouseover',...);
```

... and check out the "data" parameter:
http://api.jquery.com/on/

e.g.:

```
function greet( event ) {
  alert( "Hello " + event.data.name );
}
$( "button" ).on( "click", {name: "Karl"}, greet );
$( "button" ).on( "click", {name: "Addy"}, greet );
```

Answer (score 2):

**Simple:**

```
$(element).on("click", ["Jesikka"],  myHandler);

function myHandler(event){
   alert(event.data);     //passed in "event.data"
}
```