# Passing a function with arguments as an argument?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments, closures

Is it possible to pass a javascript function with arguments as an argument?

Example:

```
$(edit_link).click( changeViewMode( myvar ) );
```

Comment: It looks like JQuery, and most likely is, but that is irrelevant. The use or parameters and functions is the same regardless of what Javascript libraries you use.

Comment: If you are working with React, consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369497/passing-a-function-with-parameters-through-props-on-reactjs

Answer (score 303, accepted):

Use a "closure":

```
$(edit_link).click(function(){ return changeViewMode(myvar); });
```

This creates an anonymous temporary function wrapper that knows about the parameter and passes it to the actual callback implementation.

Comment: If you're wanting to call a function on an object, you need to call bind(). myObj.click( function() { this.doSomething(); }.bind( myObj ) ); That will make "this" be myObj.

Comment: Isn't this a performance issue when dealing with a lot of these? E.g. You're rendering a onPress in a Row and you have 10,000 rows. This creates a new anonymous temporary function wrapper for each Row. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @JoshuaPinter The technique itself is not an issue. If you need the same function call 10,000 times, you can simply save the wrapper in a variable, so you create it only once. If you need to pass 10,000 different contexts, there is little you can do. Beware of premature optimization: As always with performance, you need to *measure* to see if there is a problem or not. Today's JavaScript engines are very powerful and might optimize code in surprising ways.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer Awesome, thanks for the tip. A friend told me it was bad practice and that you should instead use `this.myFunction = this.myFunction.bind(this)` in your `constructor` method. But, like you said, when you have to pass different contexts to it for each one, like all different rows that you click on to open that row's detail page, it's not avoidable.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer , lets say myvar is a string and its changed between two consecutive invocations of passing changeViewMode as a closure, but changeViewMode always receives the first value of myvar , 

I want to call closure function with different argument value assigned to same myvar variable,

Comment: In ES6 you can simplify it by using arrow functions.
$(edit_link).click(() => changeViewMode(myvar));

Answer (score 52):

Use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). Quoting MDN:

> The **`bind()`** method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

It is supported by all major browsers, including IE9+.

Your code should look like this:

```
$(edit_link).click(changeViewMode.bind(null, myvar));
```

Side note: I assume you are in global context, i.e. `this` variable is `window`; otherwise use `this` instead of `null`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. Used it like this:
`$.ajax(url).done(handler.bind(this, var1, var2));`

Comment: Which option is best ? Using closure or using the bind function ? Please let me know if there is any performance impact

Comment: @Varun See [Why is bind slower than a closure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638305/why-is-bind-slower-than-a-closure)

Comment: I've been using `fn.bind(this)` to resolve the dreaded `this` confusion in callback functions without understanding the broader purpose of `bind` – but now I get it! Thanks 

Answer (score 19):

No, but you can pass one without parameters, and do this:

```
$(edit_link).click(
  function() { changeViewMode(myvar); }
);
```

So you're passing an anonymous function with no parameters, that function then calls your parameterized function with the variable in the closure

Answer (score 16):

Or if you are using es6 you should be able to use an arrow function

```
$(edit_link).click(() => changeViewMode(myvar));
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, like this:

```
$(edit_link).click(function() { changeViewMode(myvar) });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

```
var message  = 'Hello World';

var callback = function(){
alert(this)
}.bind(message);
```

and then

```
function activate(callback){
  callback && callback();
}

activate(callback);
```

Or if your callback contains more flexible logic you can pass object.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/chameleon_iguan/znu48yo5/1/)

Answer (score 2):

This is an example following Ferdinand Beyer's approach:

```
function function1()
{
    function2(function () { function3("parameter value"); });
}
function function2(functionToBindOnClick)
{
    $(".myButton").click(functionToBindOnClick);
}
function function3(message) { alert(message); }
```

In this example the "parameter value" is passed from function1 to function3 through function2 using a function wrap.