# Grabbing value onCheck from Checkbox/ListItem

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

Let's say I have the following rendered by a `React.Component` implementing `material-ui` components:

```
{data.map(value => (
     <ListItem
         key={data.indexOf(value)}
         primaryText={value}
         leftCheckbox={
         <Checkbox
           onCheck={this.props.handleAddOption}>
           </Checkbox>}>
      </ListItem>
```

When the `Checkbox` is chosen, I want to push the value into the array in `state`

```
handleAddOption = (value) => {

    this.setState((....))

}
```

How do I go about doing that?

**UPDATE**
found the solution here [Passing a function with parameters through props on reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369497/passing-a-function-with-parameters-through-props-on-reactjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the value from the `CheckBox` component to the function prop. You can do this by:

```
<ListItem
  key={data.indexOf(value)}
  primaryText={value}
  leftCheckbox={
    <Checkbox
      onCheck={(e, isChecked) => this.props.handleAddOption(value, isChecked)}>
    </Checkbox>}>
</ListItem>
```

And for your handler:

```
handleAddOption(value, isChecked) {
  this.setState((prevState, props) => {
    // Get the old state's value, sticking with immutable pattern
    let yourProperty = prevState.yourProperty;
    // Determine if the value already exists in your property's array
    const exists = yourProperty.find(v => v === value);

    if (isChecked) {
      // If the checkbox is checked...
      // If the property exists, don't do anything
      // If it isn't there, add it
      !exists && yourProperty.push(value);
    } else {
      // If the checkbox is NOT checked...
      // If the property exists, filter the array to remove it
      // If it isn't there, do nothing
      exists && (yourProperty = yourProperty.filter(v => v !== value));
    }

    // Return the new state
    return { yourProperty };
  });
}
```

**UPDATE**
I've updated the solution a bit with documentation and a couple of typos, and created a working example on CodeSandBox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/pj0m4w3qp7

Comment: Thank you, a bit advanced but it seems logical. However, I receive the following error when I implement this:
`input is a void element tag and must neither have children nor use dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Comment: @KobbiGal I updated the answer with comments for clarity. Also fixed a couple of mistakes (forgot array.push only returns the index, not the array), as well as a CodeSandbox example for you