# Passing a function to a component but receiving undefined

Tags: reactjs

In my app, I need to pass a function to a "menu" component that will render a necessary content in a main component content area.

This is that I do in my main component:

```js
new Menu({ props: {contentComponentMounter: this.mountContentComponent}})
```

In my Menu Component, I have the following:

```js
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        console.log(props, props.contentComponentMounter);    
    };
```

This is the console output i get:

[image]

As you can see, when I try to log props, I see exactly what is expected but for `props.contentComponentMounter` it shows undefined. Why is this the case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a function with parameters through props on reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369497/passing-a-function-with-parameters-through-props-on-reactjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call it like `props.props.contentComponentMounter`. Because notice what your arguments looks like in this call `{ props: {contentComponentMounter: this.mountContentComponent}}` also, the same can be seen from your `console.log` output.

You will not get undefined if you pass the arguments to `Menu` constructor as `new Menu({contentComponentMounter: this.mountContentComponent})`.

Answer (score 1):

constructor(props) {
        super(props);

```
    console.log(props, props.props.contentComponentMounter);    
};
```