# jQuery .click() function called automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener, jquery-events, jquery-click-event

I have an event listener set up on a button using jQuery, and for some reason the function within the click listener is called without the button being clicked. I know that usually functions are anonymous in listeners, but it won't work as an anonymous function. The function I am calling also has to accept parameters, which is why I don't think I can just call a reference to the function. Any ideas on how I can fix the problem of the function getting called without a click even registered and still pass the necessary parameters to the function?

```
$('#keep-both').click(keepBothFiles(file, progress, audioSrc));
```

calls this function

```
function keepBothFiles(file, progress, audioSrc) {
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979337/how-can-i-pass-arguments-to-event-handlers-in-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979337/how-can-i-pass-arguments-to-event-handlers-in-jquery)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're referencing the function incorrectly. Try this instead:

```
$('#keep-both').click(function(){
  keepBothFiles(file, progress, audioSrc);
});
```

Whenever you use the syntax `funcName()`, the `()` tell the interpreter to immediately invoke the function. The `.click` method requires that you pass it a reference to a function. Function references are passed by name only. You could also do:

```
$('#keep-both').click(keepBothFiles);
```

But you can't pass it your other arguments. It's given an event object by default

Answer (score 3):

You must pass a function reference to the .click() function, not the result of calling a function.  When you include the `()` like this `keepBothFiles(...)` at the end of the function name, you are telling javascript to execute the function now.  When you just use the name of the function like `keepBothFiles`, you are getting a reference to the function (which can be called later).

You are currently calling your function immediately and then passing the return value of that function (which is not a function reference) to the `.click()` function, thus it does not do what you want.

The click handler callback function is passed exactly one parameter (the event) in jQuery so you cannot have it call your `keepBothFiles(file, progress, audioSrc)` function directly like you have it.

Instead, it could be done like this with a second wrapper function:

```
$('#keep-both').click(function(e) {
    keepBothFiles(file, progress, audioSrc);
});
```

Comment: i would also just pass in e into the keepBothFiles function if i needed that too right?

Comment: @IlanBiala - yes, if `e` was relevant to the function, you could pass it in too.