# Javascript function inside document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Why doesn't any javascript function written inside document.ready be directly called from an event in jsp?

Eg:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     function abc()
     {
          //Some stuff here
     }
});
```

From something like:

```
<input id="a" type="button" onclick="abc();">
```

Comment: show your markup or make a fiddle

Comment: Because it's out of scope. Attach the event _in JavaScript_.

Comment: Alternatively, move the function declaration outside of `document.ready`. There is no reason to put it there.

Comment: @FelixKling you don't know that actually. Not with such a simplified code snippet.

Comment: @Mchl: Fair enough, but I only see two reasons to keep a function declaration in there: If it is a closure and/or to keep the global scope clean. But aside from that, one does not have to wait to declare a function until the document is ready. I think there are many developers who put all their code inside the ready handler because they just don't know better.

Comment: @FelixKling Agreed. I would usually assume such a function is a closure.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because it's not available in the global scope. Any function defined within the anonymous function you pass as an argument to `$.ready()` is only available within that function.

To achieve what you want to do you need something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     function abc() {}

     $('#a').on('click',abc);
});
```

For more information on function scope see [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope)

Comment: How can we pass parameter to function abc() in the above code?

Comment: @Pranav: [How can I pass arguments to event handlers in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/979337/218196)