# AJAX Delete Not Working Entity Framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I wonder why its not working, here is the code

View

```
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deletefunction(@item.PhotoId)"/>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int photoid)
{
    var imgDelete = db.Photos.Where(x => x.PhotoId == photoid).FirstOrDefault();
    if (imgDelete == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    db.Photos.Remove(imgDelete);
    db.SaveChanges();
    System.IO.File.Delete(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + imgDelete.ImagePath);
    System.IO.File.Delete(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + imgDelete.ThumbPath);
    return null;
}
```

JQUERY/AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function deletefunction(photoid) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Delete")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { photoid: photoid },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert: ("Success")
                },
                error: {
                    alert: ("Error")
                }
            });
        };
    });
</script>
```

im new to jquery and ajax, im trying to delete the photo without refreshing the page, am i in the correct path?

Comment: Whats not working? What errors are you getting? Are you hitting the controller method?

Comment: im getting no error and also no response from controller i set a breakpoint

Comment: Check your browser console for errors (and why are you returning `null`?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke what should i return? the method has no view and i dont want to use RedirectToAction

Comment: the error is deletefunction is undefined

Comment: Keep your delete function in `<head>` section and try once..

Comment: Not a requirement, but try to return `Json` data from your `ActionResult`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao did that no avail.

Comment: Rather than polluting your markup with behavior, use unobtrusive javascript - `<input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" data-id="@item.PhotoId">` and in the script use `$('.delete').click(function() { var photoid = $(this).data('id'); ...`

Comment: again you are getting same error? `deletefunction` is undefined ? Do not keep it inside `document.ready` plus better if you opt @StephenMuecke's suggestion..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao should i use return return Json(new { photoid = photoid});

Comment: No no.. `return Json(new {message="true"},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)` or `false` based on the success and failure..

Comment: @Nevi, Refer [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504253/javascript-function-inside-document-ready) for why you current implementation will not work

Comment: contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",

Comment: @StephenMuecke i think i made it work, now its deleting the photo but it seems i need to hit F5 to see if the photo is deleted

Comment: Do you mean the photo is actually displayed on the page? If so, then you need to remove the element from the DOM in the success callback (which is also why you should be returning a value indicating success or otherwise - e.g. `return Json(true);` and then `success: function (result) { if (result) { $(yourPhoto).remove(); }`

Comment: yes @StephenMuecke how do i do that?

Comment: @Nevi use this `<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deletefunction(@item.PhotoId)" id='@item.PhotoId'/>` and use `$('#'+photoid+'').remove()` to remove it

Comment: Write `function deletefunction(photoid) { //your code }` outside `$(document).ready(function () { \\your other code });`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to attach `click event` to your button instead of writing `javascript` in markup. Consider the below markup:

```
<input type="button" class="delete" value="Delete" data-picid="@item.photoId"/>
```

Now attach a `click event` to `.delete` as below:

```
$('.delete').on('click',function(){
    var photoId=$(this).attr('data-picid');//gets your photoid
    $.ajax({
          url: '@Url.Action("Delete")',
          type: 'POST',
          data: JSON.stringify({ photoid: photoId }),
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
          dataType: "json", //return type you are expecting from server
          success: function (result) {
              //access message from server as result.message and display proper message to user
              alert: ("Success")
          },
          error: {
              alert: ("Error")
          }
    });
});
```

Your Controller then:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int photoid)
{
    var imgDelete = db.Photos.Where(x => x.PhotoId == photoid).FirstOrDefault();
    if (imgDelete == null)
    {
        return Json(new{ message=false},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);//return false in message variable
    }
    db.Photos.Remove(imgDelete);
    db.SaveChanges();
    System.IO.File.Delete(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + imgDelete.ImagePath);
    System.IO.File.Delete(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + imgDelete.ThumbPath);
    return Json(new{ message=false},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //return true if everything is fine
}
```

Once photo is deleted based on the success or failure your can do it as below in `success` of `ajax, but before that store a reference to your`button` as below:

```
$('.delete').on('click',function(){
    var photoId=$(this).attr('data-picid');//gets your photoid
    var $this=$(this);
    $.ajax({
          url: '@Url.Action("Delete")',
          type: 'POST',
          data: JSON.stringify({ photoid: photoId }),
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
          dataType: "json", //return type you are expecting from server
          success: function (result) {
              if(result.message)
              { 
                   $this.closest('yourrootparentselector').remove();
                   //here yourrootparentselector will be the element which holds all 
                   //your photo and delete button too
              }
          },
          error: {
              alert: ("Error")
          }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your given mark up you I suggest to add one more root parent for your each `image` and `delete` button as below:

```
<div style="margin-top: 17px;">
   <div id="links"> 
        @foreach (var item in Model.Content) 
        { 
            <div class="rootparent"> <!--rootparent here, you can give any classname-->
                 <a href="@item.ImagePath" title="@item.Description" data-gallery> 
                     <img src="@item.ThumbPath" alt="@item.Description" class="img-rounded" style="margin-bottom:7px;" /> 
                  </a> 
                  <input type="button" class="delete" value="Delete" data-picid="@item.PhotoId" /> 
            </div>

         } 
    </div>
</div>
```

Now you can write this in success

```
$this.closest('.rootparent').remove()
```

Comment: this works, how can i remove the element photo to DOM after successfully deleting

Comment: <div style="margin-top: 17px;">
        <div id="links">
            @foreach (var item in Model.Content)
            {
                <a href="@item.ImagePath" title="@item.Description" data-gallery>
                    <img src="@item.ThumbPath" alt="@item.Description" class="img-rounded" style="margin-bottom:7px;" />
                </a>
                <input type="button" class="delete" value="Delete" data-picid="@item.PhotoId" />
            }
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: is there such this as $this.closest('.rootparent').remove().where(photoid = photoid)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

        });
     function deletefunction(photoid) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Delete")',
                    type: 'POST',    
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { photoid: photoid },
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert: ("Success")
                    },
                    error: {
                        alert: ("Error")
                    }
                });
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: You need to remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` or this will not work. Either that or you need to stringify the data.