# onsubmit function not called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to validate a form with jQuery without using any plugin and my first problem is that the function `validateLogin()` is not called after hitting submit . In the below snippet everything is working just fine ,but on my pc is not .

```js
function validateLogin() {
      $('#login-form').find('input').each(function() {
      
      var $this = $(this);
      var inputName = $this.attr('name');
      var value = $this.val();
      
      alert(" value of "+ inputName + " = " + value );
    })
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="login-form" id="login-form" name="login" method="get" onsubmit="return validateLogin();" >
                 
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="login-label" for="usermail">Already a member?</label>
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="usermail" id="usermail" placeholder="Username or Email" value="">
                  <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                  <button class="form-control btn btn-danger" type="submit" id="login-button" >Login</button>
                </div> <!-- end form-group -->
                
              </form> <!-- end login-form -->
```

edit: so I was getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: validateLogin is not defined " in the console .After a quick research I found out that validateLogin shouldn't be inside `$(document).ready` . Can someone explain why ?

Comment: Do you see any errors on console ?

Comment: So what is different between your snipplet and your actual code since the example runs?

Comment: <input class="form-control btn btn-danger" type="button" id="login-button" value="Login" onclick="validateLogin()"> Please try this

Comment: Have you tried to do `event.preventDefault();` as the first line of your handler. Also I am not sure you need to use `return` as a prefix, just call the function.

Comment: @dinesh type="button" does not submit.... so not going to work

Comment: i would guess that something is with his browser not with the code.. try different browser

Comment: @Delliriumand return is perfectly fine.

Comment: @epascarello I was writing to call the `validateLogin()` function

Comment: There is no need to call the function.... submit does it... The code works, OP has an issue some place else.

Comment: `jquery/1.2.3` <--- yikes, over 8 years old.

Comment: Maybe you accidentally pressed on "prevent...." from showing in the alert.  Blocked form submission to 'http://stacksnippets.net/js' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set.

Comment: Try to close and open the tab.

Comment: in the console I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: validateLogin is not defined " when using onsubmit or onclick .

Comment: try to add return false or return true in the end of validateLogin()

Comment: I updated the original post .

Comment: @Adrian.I The reason why you need to have the function out of the document.ready is because you already bind your button with the function. Therefore the document doesn't have to be ready

Comment: @Adrian.I this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504253/javascript-function-inside-document-ready

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
onclick="validateForm()"
```

This will automatically validate the form the moment the login button is clicked. It also will probably make your js code a bit less complicated. Also, are there any errors in the console?