# Onsubmit not working in javascript using php

Tags: javascript, php

I have adding dynamic row using Javascript in php. I need to check the validation. I am using onsubmit for validation I have got the error message when am not entering the value, if am entering the value is not post and not fetch the values also.
    **Example code:**

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return validate();">  
var row = table.insertRow(2).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+table_len+"'><td></td><td id='pickup"+table_len+"'><input type='text'  id='pickup' name='pickup' onkeypress='return blockSpecialChar(event,this)'  class='myTextBox1' onblur='UpperCase(this)' maxlength='8'  value='' style='width:70px;text-align:left;'   required></td><td> <input type='submit' class='center' style='margin-left: 8px;align:center;padding: 1px 4px;' id='submit"+table_len+"' name='submit' value='Save' class='save' > <input type='button' style='margin-left: 6px;align:center;padding: 1px 7px;' value='Cancel'  class='center' onclick='cancel_row_add("+table_len+")'></td></tr><br>";
<script type="text/javascript">
function Validate()
{
    if(document.getElementById('pickup').value == '')
    {
    alert('Please enter pickup Name');
    document.getElementById('pickup').focus();
    return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your function Validate has the letter V capitalized, but on the submit its all lowercase

Comment: `var row =....` seems a javascript code running outside `<script></script>` . Is your code really working? Please add full code not chunks of it. Chunks made your question unclear. Also `validate() !==Validate()`. `v` word have problem there(lowercase-uppercase)

Answer (score 0):

`Javascript` functions are case sensitive.

Change `validation()` to `Validation()` in onsubmit

Comment: Where do you see validation?

Comment: It needs to be added as a comment/suggestion under question and it will go under TYPO mistakes.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion! :)

Answer (score 0):

For starters. Change:

`<form name="myForm" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return validate();">`

to

`<form name="myForm" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return Validate();">`

I don't know what you're trying here:
`var row = table.insertRow(2).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+table_len+"'> // .... code` But it seems like you're trying to run JS code outside `<script>` tags. Move it into the `<script>`. Since you're trying to get the ID `pickup` in your `Validate()` function.

Maybe try adding an ID to your form. like: `id="myForm"` and try an onclick event (and remove the onsubmit attribute):

```
$("#myForm").on('click', function(){
    alert('Please enter pickup Name');
    document.getElementById('pickup').focus();
    return false;
});
```

Add an ID to your submit button e.g.: `<input type="button" id="formSubmitBtn">` and try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function Validate(){
        if(document.getElementById('pickup').value == '')
        {
            alert('Please enter pickup Name');
            document.getElementById('pickup').focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
    $("#formSubmitBtn").on('click',Validate);
});
```

> And if all of this doesn't work. Open the developer console by pressing `F12` and clicking console. Click on the submit button and see what kind of JS Errors you get.

Comment: Please read this thread:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504253/javascript-function-inside-document-ready

Comment: Oh woops. Forget about that. Bit early in the morning for me. Will edit.

Comment: More morning shaking ... `$("#myForm").on('click'...)` doesn't make sense when `#myForm` is a form element ...

Comment: Yeah woops. Need that `$("#myForm") -> $("buttonID")`