# Javascript not working when in .ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have some jquery I wanted to use with this vanilla javascript, I was hoping to put this script inside my .ready function so I can manipulate the variables with jquery. This code creates an animation and displays when outside of the .ready function. Why dose this not work while in this function and how will I be able to get it to work?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var particles = [];
    function setup() {
      createCanvas(400, 400);
      angleMode(DEGREES);
      translate(200, 200);
      noStroke();
      for (var i = 40; i >= 0; i--) {
        var r = i * random(5, 6) + 50;
        var angle = random(0, 360);
        for (var j = 50; j >= 0; j--) {
          r -= 0.1;
          angle += random(2, 9);
          particles.push(new Particle(r, angle, random(1, 5)));
        }
      }
      frameRate(20);
    }
    function draw() {
      background(0);
      translate(200, 200);
      var r = 210;
      for (var i = particles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (particles[i].r < random(20, 25)) {
          particles[i].r = r;
        } else {
          particles[i].update();
          particles[i].show();
        }
      }
    }
    function Particle(r, theta, size) {
      this.r = r;
      this.theta = theta;
      this.size = size;
      this.update = function() {
        this.r -= random(0.5, 0.8) / Math.log10(this.r * 2);
        this.theta += random(0.9, 1.5) / Math.log10(this.r / 5);
      };
      this.show = function() {
        fill(255, Math.min(2 * this.r, 255));
        ellipse(this.r * sin(this.theta), this.r * cos(this.theta), this.size);
      };
    }
});
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504253/javascript-function-inside-document-ready

Comment: on a first sight I would say a big difference is your particles variable is not global when in ready function but is when outside. I didn't investigate really but that seems an obvious difference to me.

Comment: crerate a fiddle for your problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the functions `setup` and `draw`, you only defined them in the current version of your code,

`setup()` and `draw()`

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have defined the `setup` and `draw` functions but did not call them.

So, add the end of your code, add two function calls

`setup()
 code()`

As a side note, if you are using jQuery only for the `document.ready` event, you can consider using `window.onload` and `DOMContentLoaded` event. You can read more about these in [this post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)