# Calling an event handler with an argument

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call an event handler with an argument. It works fine without an argument.

Where am I going wrong here?

```
var box = $("#box");

function changeColor (a) {
    $(this).css("background", a);
}

box.click(changeColor("green"));
```

Comment: All arguments are evaluated first. So if you have `foo(bar())`, `bar` is called first and its return value is passed to `foo`.

Comment: Also a duplicate of [How can I pass arguments to event handlers in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/979337/218196)

Comment: @navigator You need to use `call()`, check my answer.

Comment: @navigator You may want to read our Help Center some. We prefer to have duplicates link back to their originals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **[call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)** to call your function inside `click` event:

```
var box = $("#box");

function changeColor (a) {
    $(this).css("background", a);
}

box.click(function(){
   changeColor.call(this, "green");
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qf6ws/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use [.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/hU9Xy/)</kbd>

```
box.click(function(){
   changeColor.call(this, "green");
});
```

Comment: @navigator check updated answer with demo --> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/hU9Xy/

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your changeColor function instead of passing it as callback. Instead you should do :

```
box.click(changeColor.bind(this, "green"));
```

The bind method creates a new function with arguments already filled, it is almost equivalent to doing :

```
box.click(function () {
    changeColor("green");   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var box = $("#box");

function changeColor (a) {
    $(this).css("background", a);
}

box.click(function(){
   changeColor("green");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign the return value of `changeColor()` to `box.click()` instead of the function itself. Wrapping `changeColor()` in a function as follows sets the `box.click()` to the function

```
box.click(function(){
   changeColor.call(this, "green")
});
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpdurham/6hD62/)

Comment: this isn't working i tried this first

Comment: The problem was that you need to use `.call()` to set the context of the function call. So you end up setting the value of `this` within the callback.  I modified my code to reflect this.